# I want to convert This array to this object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

```
const movies = [
  { name: "Escape from Pretoria", year: 2020 },
  { name: "Good Will Hunting", year: 1997 },
  { name: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { name: "Tarzan", year: 1999 },
  { name: "Titanic", year: 1997 },
  { name: "The Imitation Game", year: 2014 },
];
```

to object like this

```
const x = {
  1997: ["Good will Hunting", "Titanic"],
  1999: ["The Matrix", "Tarazan"],
  2014: ["The Imitation Game"],
  2020: ["Escape from Pretoria"],
};
```

Using reduce() or another way .. thank you!

Comment: Cool, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key

Comment: You need to show an attempt to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solutions is great but in this case `forEach` method is faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const movies = [
  { name: "Escape from Pretoria", year: 2020 },
  { name: "Good Will Hunting", year: 1997 },
  { name: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { name: "Tarzan", year: 1999 },
  { name: "Titanic", year: 1997 },
  { name: "The Imitation Game", year: 2014 },
];

let obj={};

movies.forEach(({year, name})=>{
  if(obj[year]){
    obj[year].push(name)
  } else {
    obj[year] = [name]
  }

})

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const movies = [
  { name: "Escape from Pretoria", year: 2020 },
  { name: "Good Will Hunting", year: 1997 },
  { name: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { name: "Tarzan", year: 1999 },
  { name: "Titanic", year: 1997 },
  { name: "The Imitation Game", year: 2014 },
];

const result = movies.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr.year]) acc[curr.year].push(curr.name)
  else acc[curr.year] = [curr.name]
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```